# Single Item Click in a list

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

With support, I have created a list of arrays populated through JSON data, and where when a user clicks on an item, it takes them to an activity page that provides them with more information about it. I have tried to accomplish this but the result so far have been unsatisfactory. In the sense that the list of arrays do display successfully, but when an item is click a blank activity page is unexpectedly shown.

Below is list of arrays activity code:

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
    public Uri list_item_bac;
    public String list_item_name;
    public String list_item_description;
    public String list_item_price;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("list_item_name", list_item_name);
                intent.putExtra("list_item_description", list_item_description);
                intent.putExtra("list_item_price",list_item_price);

                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Below is the single item click

```
public class EventSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("list_item_description");
        list_item_price = i.getStringExtra("list_item_price");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView txtprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtdescription.setText(list_item_description);
        txtprice.setText(list_item_price);


    }
```

Below is the single item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
    }
```

Update

```
    public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

        private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
        private GridView gv;
        private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
        private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
        public Uri list_item_bac;
        public String list_item_name;
        public String list_item_description;
        public String list_item_price;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
            gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
            //download JSON
            listDownload();


            GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_name);
                    intent.putExtra("list_item_description", list_item_description);
                    intent.putExtra("list_item_price",list_item_price);

                    startActivity(intent); //start Activity
                }
            });
        }
        public void listDownload(){
            RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
            volley.add(json);
        }

        private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
            return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        //your JSON Array
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                            container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                    }
                };
            };


        private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
            return new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
            };
        }

        //object JSON
        private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
            long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
            String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
            String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
            String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
            return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
        }
    }

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

**Update 2**
Event List Activity

```
public class Events_List {
    public long id;
    public String list_item_title;
    public String list_item_price;
    public String list_item_description;
    public Uri url;

    public Events_List(long id, String list_item_title, String list_item_description, String list_item_price, Uri url){
        this.id = id;
        this.list_item_title = list_item_title;
        this.list_item_description = list_item_description;
        this.list_item_price = list_item_price;
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

Comment: post logcat stack-trace and make sure you have declared EventSingleItemActivity in `androidmanifest.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

```
intent.putExtra("list_item_name", list_item_name);
intent.putExtra("list_item_description", list_item_description);
intent.putExtra("list_item_price",list_item_price);
```

Those values are empty because they are never used or initialized, so by the time you switch activity and get the values from the intent it will return empty string thus giving you no result

**solution:**

use your `arraylist` object `container` and use the position of the `onItemClick` and get the values using the get method of the arraylist

**sample:**

```
intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_name);
```

remember that your class `Events_List` must have a **getter** method for `List_item_name`

**UPDATE:**

```
public class Events_List {
public long id;
public String list_item_title;
public String list_item_price;
public String list_item_description;
public Uri url;

public Events_List(long id, String list_item_title, String list_item_description, String list_item_price, Uri url){
    this.id = id;
    this.list_item_title = list_item_title;
    this.list_item_description = list_item_description;
    this.list_item_price = list_item_price;
    this.url = url;
}

public String getList_item_title()
{
    return this.list_item_title;
}

public String getList_item_price()
{
    return this.list_item_price;
}

public String getList_item_description()
{
    return this.list_item_description;
}

}
```

**how to use it:**

```
    intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_title());
intent.putExtra("list_item_description", container.get(position).getList_item_description());
intent.putExtra("list_item_price",container.get(position).getList_item_description());
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and clarification. There seems to be a typo in the following line:intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_name); I think you may have meant intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).get(List_item_name); what do you exactly mean by getter method

Comment: @user3827788 what line?

Comment: line:intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_name); I think you may have meant intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).get(List_item_name); How would I workout the getter method

Comment: @user3827788 no my code is right, that is a `getter` method name for the class  Events_List of yours which I made up but you can change it. learn how to do it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, but I then I receive the following error - getList_item_name cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Post your Event_List class also.

Comment: @user3827788 post Event_List class

Comment: Thanks brother for all of your help and support. This has resolve my issue.

Comment: @user3827788 anytime :))

Comment: A quick question. In my single item click I was retrieving many of the same information that was shown in the list of arrays. I have included new JSON data that would only be displayed on the single item click, and hence have created a new variable known as single_list_item_description, and have referenced it as well. Unfortunately this information is not shown when the activity is loaded. I am not too sure if this is an issue with the code or with my JSON code produced using PHP. I have added the update under update 3 of my initial post.

Comment: @user3827788 that would be another question post it so others can see.